# Failed to start/test Eclipse Che workspace using multi-machine stacks

Tags: eclipse-che

Eclipse Che version: 6.11.0

Started as docker container;

multi-user mode;

I tested with several of the predefined multi-machine stacks with mysql db config, if the test run begins with the db machine, it seems to hang there forever, never proceeds with the dev-machine start process;

When it times out, I got the following error message:

`Could not start workspace xxx. Reason:Server 'exec-agent/http' in machine 'db' not available.`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I need to open a range of ephemeral ports on my OS in order to let the agent status check to pass.

Reference: [Eclipse Che Configuration](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/docker-config.html)

```
# Check to see if firewall is running:
systemctl status firewalld

# Check for list of open ports
# Verify that ports 8080tcp, 32768-65535tcp are open
firewall-cmd --list-ports

# Optionally open ports on your local firewall:
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
... and so on
```

Actual command I use:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=32768-65535/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

For completion, you also need to green light 5050(for keycloak) and `$CHE_PORT` ports for Eclipse Che to run normally.

Can't turn off `firewalld`. Otherwise it would complain about not being able to execute some `iptable` commands.